# How can I track a HTTP request when the app receiving the request makes subsequent requests to other apps

Tags: web-services, servlets, routes, monitoring

I have a set of applications which together make up a product.

Say: App1, App2 and App3.

When a HTTP request comes to App1, after some internal processing, it sends a request to App2 and then to App3, receives necessary info from App2 and App3, compiles and sends a response to the client.

How can I track the complete journey/lifecycle of the initial HTTP request?

I have tried the following:
Add a header to the initial request: Transaction-Id: UUID
to track the particular transaction. My Apache server has a listener to read this transactionId and do the needful.
But once the request reaches App1, the header is lost while sending request to App2 and App3. I am unable to track App2 and App3

I don't want to implement the additional logic in App1 of manually adding the Transaction header to App2 & App3 requests.

Comment: You probably start a new request from App1 to App2/3. So there is no way around attaching the header attribute again.

Comment: But isn't this request a sub request of the original request happening in the same request response thread at a macro level?

Comment: No, this is a completely new http request.